# Issue in transpiling .ts files : what's wrong with my webpack config and with my tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, webpack-5, electron-forge

This is my `tsconfig.json` file :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 16",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["es2021", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Based on what we read here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include
"
If a glob pattern doesn’t include a file extension, then only files with supported extensions are included (e.g. .ts, .tsx, and .d.ts by default, with .js and .jsx if [allowJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs) is set to true).
"

all `.ts files` should be compiled.

As indicated here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#installation I also specified the extensions in the `webpack.config` files:

`webpack.renderer.config.js` :

```
const rules = require('./webpack.rules');
const plugins = require('./webpack.plugins');

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css'],
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      'stream': require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      'buffer': require.resolve('buffer'),
      'util': require.resolve('util'),
      'assert': require.resolve('assert'),
      'http': require.resolve('stream-http'),
      'url': require.resolve('url'),
      'https': require.resolve('https-browserify'),
      'os': require.resolve('os-browserify'),
      'path': require.resolve('path-browserify')
    },
  },
};
```

`webpack.main.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: {
    main: './src/main/index.ts'
  },
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css', '.json'],
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      'stream': require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      'buffer': require.resolve('buffer'),
      'util': require.resolve('util'),
      'assert': require.resolve('assert'),
      'http': require.resolve('stream-http'),
      'url': require.resolve('url'),
      'https': require.resolve('https-browserify'),
      'os': require.resolve('os-browserify'),
      'path': require.resolve('path-browserify')
    },
  },
};
```

`webpack.rules.js` :

```
module.exports = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    // We're specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
    // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
    test: /native_modules\/.+\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.pcss$/,
    type: 'asset',
    use: {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          "postcss-preset-env",
        ],
      },
    },
  }
];
```

And this is my `package.json` file :

```
{
  "name": "playground",
  "productName": "Playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Playground",
  "main": ".webpack/main",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "raphy",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "executableName": "playground"
      },
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "forgetypescriptreactwebpack"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {
            "maintainer": "Raphael Stonehorse"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip"
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/app/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/app/renderer.ts",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/main/preload/preload.ts"
                  },
                  "name": "main_window"
                },
                {
                  "html": "./src/app_A/index_A.html",
                  "js": "./src/app_A/renderer_A.ts",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/main/preload/preload.ts"
                  },
                  "name": "window_type_a"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-flatpak": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-snap": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-electronegativity": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@types/better-sqlite3": "^7.5.0",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.190",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "1.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "electron": "17",
    "electron-extensions": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.2.11",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zendeskgarden/react-tabs": "^8.52.0",
    "@zendeskgarden/react-theming": "^8.52.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "^7.5.3",
    "better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers": "^7.5.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "electron-log": "^4.4.7",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-ipc": "^11.1.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-select": "^5.3.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

But I do not see the compiled files of :

```
(base) raphy@pc:~/Playground/src/main/workers$ ls -lah
total 20K
drwxrwxr-x 2 raphy raphy 4.0K Jun 13 17:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 raphy raphy 4.0K Jun 13 17:25 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  298 Jun 12 17:27 server-handlers.ts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  888 Jun 12 17:39 server.ts
(base) raphy@pc:~/Playground/src/main/workers$
```

in the corresponding folder :

```
(base) raphy@pc:~/Playground/.webpack/main$ ls -lah
total 1.5M
drwxrwxr-x 3 raphy raphy 4.0K Jun 13 18:11 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 raphy raphy 4.0K Jun 13 18:11 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 684K Jun 13 18:11 index.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 823K Jun 13 18:11 index.js.map
drwxrwxr-x 2 raphy raphy 4.0K Jun 13 18:11 native_modules
(base) raphy@pc:~/Playground/.webpack/main$
```

What's wrong with my `webpack configuration` or / and with my `ts.config.json` file ?
How to make the traspiling work?